# Drawing graphics in ASP.NET web application: pie and rectangle

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I wish to draw some graphics in a asp.net web application page on some percentages, what is the code required? I'm asking specially for piechart and rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the data visualization stuff (charting) that comes with .net 3.5 and 4.

There is a downloadable Visual Studio solution (an asp.net web application project) that shows examples of different types of charts and corresponding code and markup:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591

Depending on your situation, you may even be able to generate pie charts, etc. without writing any code.