# What can I draw on in an Asp.net Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, picturebox

I am attempting to develop a web page in which the codebehind draws diagrams. I have an analagous forms application which uses a picturebox, and the replies to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718433/cant-find-picturebox-in-toolbox) suggest I should use an Image Control.

But it isn't obvious how I should set about drawing my triangles and circles on this control. So: is an image control what I want? If so, can someone direct me to a tutorial or an example as to how to draw on it?

If it isn't, what should I be using? (What I am drawing isn't a [graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376950/drawing-graphics-in-asp-net-web-application-pie-and-rectangle).)

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this on the server. Use client-side libraries. What you can do on the server - is *prepare data* for the diagram, send it to the client to do actual drawing.

For example [mxGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html) library has a nice .NET component that builds XML for the diagram on the server and then client-side draws diagram based on that XML.

The above is a commercial products, but there're free alternatives out there as well.